# Python request SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-3.5

I have written a Python3.7.1 code, and I need to run it in Python3.5 (because I have to run it from Raspberry), an error shows up:

```
teams = requests.get(f'http://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/{league}/standings', headers=headers, timeout = 10).json()
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The error appears on the first comma (...standings', headers...)

I suppose this is because of python3.5 don't support the same things that 3.7.

I have tried to install Python 3.7 in raspberry but have no good results

```
teams = requests.get(f'http://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/{league}/standings', headers=headers, timeout = 10).json()
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that the f string is supported since python 3.6. As you are using python 3.5, you can use an equivalent:

```py
url = 'http://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/{}/standings'.format(league)
```

[Here](https://pyformat.info/) you can find some information about string formatting.